# Project Server 2013 Webpart with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, project, csom

I want create a webpart to display information from Project Server 2013. So that I can implement my webpart on a new page on Project Server.

My approache is to create a SharePoint 2013 Webpart and use Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll

```
private void GetProjectsListData()
    {
        context = new ClientContext(pwaPath);
        projSvr = new ProjectServer(context);

        context.Load(projSvr.Projects);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        gdvProjectsList.DataSource = projSvr.Projects;
        gdvProjectsList.DataBind();
    }
```

But I get an 401 Authentication error. I think the SP use the IIS application pool user and not my user. 
If I use the CSOM in a console application it is working.

Is this the correct approach to do this or should I use the PSI? Or how can i impersionate to tell the CSOM to use another user?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: no sry it's not working

Comment: is this still in problem? if yess, I can suggest for solve this.cz i have developed web part using csom too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible due to the fact what you already found, that the SP ClientContext works under the IIS App Pool account. For a OnPremise farm solution there is no way to get the CSOM working with the current user, expect you can provide username and password (but i think this is no solution).

I would prefer to use PSI or JSOM. Both are working for me. Also REST and the OData Reporting Feeds are  working fine but the OData feeds are returning ALL data.